# Нужно ускорить алгоритм. Задача из учебника Меньшикова

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

[Условие взято отсюда.](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=634&chapterid=612)

> Даны N целых чисел X1, X2, ..., XN. Расставить между ними знаки "+" и
>   "-" так, чтобы значение получившегося выражения было равно заданному
>   целому S.

**Входные данные:**

> В первой строке находятся числа N и S. В следующей строке - N чисел
>   через пробел. 2 <= N <= 24, 0 <= Xi <= 50 000 000, -1 000 000 000 <= S
>   <= 1 000 000 000.

**Выходные данные:**

> Если получить требуемый результат невозможно, вывести "No solution",
>   если можно, то вывести равенство. Если решение не единственное,
>   вывести любое.

---

### Нужно уменьшить время работы алгоритма.

Мой код:

```
#import time

#   num1 -- массив чисел, seed -- строка '0' и '1', которые рассматриваются как операторы '-' и '+'
#   функция проверяет равенство выражения из последовательно расставленных чисел и операторов из num1 и seed числу num2

def che(num1,num2,seed):
    a = num1[0]
    for i,j in zip(num1[1:], seed):
        if j == '1':
            a += i
        else:
            a -= i
    if a == num2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#   возвращает строку из '0' и '1', которая потом дополняется до нужной длины
#   чтобы было легче итерироваться, решил представить строку из '+' и '-' как двоичное число
def gena (leng):
    for i in range(2**leng):
        yield bin(i)[2:]

#   ввод чисел
s1 = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
s2 = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))

#start_time = time.time()

#   базовая проверка на четность, иногда экономит время
if sum(s2)%2 != s1[1]%2:
    print ("No solution")
else:
    for i in gena(leng = s1[0]-1):
        seed = '-'*(s1[0]-1 - len(i)) + i # дополним строку до нужной длины
        if che(num1 = s2, num2 = s1[1], seed = seed) == True:
            #   формируем ответ
            seed += '='
            m = ''
            for x,y in zip(s2,seed):
                if y == '1':
                    m += str(x)+'+'
                elif y == '=':
                    m += str(x)+'=' 
                else:
                     m += str(x)+'-'
            m += str(s1[1])
            print(m)
            break
    else:
        print ('No solution')

#print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Пожалуйста, напишите, что можно изменить (или идею, если менять нужно все).

Comment: Возможен вариант без перебора, при котором нужно образовывать пачки равные s. Но нужно не потерять отдельные случаи. Идеальный вариант если их получается нечётное количество без остатков. Если нечётное и с остатком то самоуничтожается ли остаток. Если пачек чётное количество - найти пачку которая может самоуничтожиться и т.д.

Comment: @EugeneDennis, не совсем понял как создавать пачки равные S.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [24]: from ast import literal_eval

In [25]: from itertools import product

In [26]: from functools import reduce

In [27]: def validate(numbers, result):
    ...:     if sum(numbers) >= result >= reduce(int.__sub__, sorted(numbers)):
    ...:         return calculate(numbers, result)
    ...:     return 'No solution'
    ...:
    ...:

In [28]: def calculate(numbers, result):
    ...:     pattern = '{}'.join(map(str, numbers))
    ...:     for i in product(['+', '-'], repeat=len(numbers)-1):
    ...:         expr = pattern.format(*i)
    ...:         if literal_eval(expr) == result:
    ...:             return expr
    ...:     return 'No solution'
    ...:
    ...:
In [29]: validate([4, 3, 2, 1], -2)
Out[29]: '4-3-2-1'

In [30]: validate([4, 3, 2, 1], 10)
Out[30]: '4+3+2+1'

In [31]: validate([4, 3, 2, 1], 11)
Out[31]: 'No solution'

In [32]: validate([4, 3, 2, 1], -10)
Out[32]: 'No solution'
```

Comment: алгоритм нужно написать самому(

Comment: @microadept даже встроенные библиотеки нельзя?

Comment: "алгоритм нужно написать самому" - этого нет в условии ;)

Comment: @ПавелДурманов, встроенные библиотеки использовать можно

Comment: @microadept тогда вместо `numexpr.evaluate` используй `eval(expr)` а `itertools` -- встроенная

Comment: @microadept переделал ответ

Comment: @ПавелДурманов, все равно не проходит по времени( , даже немного медленнее моего, если верить сайту.

Comment: @microadept при каких входных данных?

Comment: @ПавелДурманов, они не указаны

Answer (score 0):

Приведу идею c минимизацией перебора, при котором нужно образовывать пачки чисел равные s. Способ нетривиальный, но возможный.
Представим входные (n отсортировали):

```
s = 5
n = [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Теперь образуем пачки из чисел по модулю:

```
ns = [[3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Это идеальный вариант - нечётное количество без остатков. Чётные пачки все получают `-`, нечётные `+`.

Вариант сложней - где внутри пачки по модулю сумма больше `s`, но есть возможность проставить знаки так чтобы получилось `s`. Может быть остаток.

```
s1 = 11
n1 = [10, 10, 9, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2]
ns1 = [[10, 4, 3], [10, 4, 3], [9, 2], [5, 3]]
```

Там разгрести все порядки, условия - будет делать то, что хотите.

Answer (score 0):

Первое число всегда входит в сумму со знаком плюс. Остальные числа разобъём на две половины. Для каждой половины переберём все комбинации знаков и составим словарь `{<сумма>: <комбинация знаков>}`. Один словарь переберём, во втором словаре отыщем такую сумму, что сумма первого числа и сумм из словарей будет равна искомой сумме (прошу прощения, везде одни суммы).

Это работает быстро, так как в словарях не более *2<sup>12</sup> (= 4096)* значений:

```
def sums(a):
    sums = {}

    def search(i, s, expr): 
        if i < 0:
            sums[s] = expr
        else:
            search(i - 1, s - a[i], f'-{a[i]}{expr}')
            search(i - 1, s + a[i], f'+{a[i]}{expr}')

    search(len(a) - 1, 0, '')
    return sums


def main():
    n, target = map(int, input().split())
    a0, *a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

    sums1 = sums(a[:n // 2])
    sums2 = sums(a[n // 2:])

    for s, e in sums1.items():
        if target - a0 - s in sums2:
            print(f'{a0}{e}{sums2[target - a0 - s]}={target}')
            break
    else:
        print('No solution')


main()
```